React useEffect cleanup closes websocket right away
I've created a React Hook that initialises and returns a socket.io-client instance.
useSocket.ts
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import io, { ManagerOptions, Socket, SocketOptions } from "socket.io-client";

export const useSocket = (
  url: string,
  opts?: Partial<ManagerOptions & SocketOptions> | undefined
): Socket => {
  const { current: socket } = useRef(io(url, opts));

  // on removing the code below, everything works as usual
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (socket) {
        socket.close();
      }
    };
  }, [socket]);

  return socket;
};

The issue is, when I'm using this in a React component and trying to emit events, no events are being emitted.
App.tsx
const App = () => {

  const socket = useSocket("http://localhost:5000");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.info("Sending handshake to server useeffect");

    console.log(socket.connected); // comes up as false

    socket.emit("handshake", "hello world"); // is not emitted
  }, [socket]);

...
}

Unable to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
Expecting the cleanup function to run when the component unmounts and not right away

Is this still relevant?
